# In practice, what are the most useful ways to visualize 2d fluid flow, to tell what is happening in the simulation? Esp for verification and debugging

Tags: fluid-dynamics, visualization, verification

My simulation creates a 2d grid of vectors and scalars (EDIT of velocity, depth etc), at 60 frames per second. Is it correct? It looks sort of right... but who knows?
How can I tell what's happening - especially for debugging?

Thoughts so far:

- Arrows for velocity field is difficult to see what's happening in small areas/fine detail. And if using length for magnitude, you have to get the scale right, or the arrows disappear (too small) or become lines (too big).

  - Or, can use colours for magnitude (standard rainbow key, to map colours to numbers). Still has the scaling problem.
- particles (dots), evenly placed and moved by the velocity field. Density of dots then implies divergence; and cirlcular motion implies vorticity.
- Green/red for curl (vorticity), clockwise/counter-clockwise
- Grey-scale for divergence (compression)
- Height field as a 3d isometric surface, with labelled axes and scales

Is it better to dump all the data to a file/s, and then visualize it later, with a separate tool? You could then move forward and backward in time, like a movie, and switch between quantities to visualize, and methods of visualizing. Maybe, in practice, just hacking the code to display different things is the best way to make progress?

I'll have to create the visualization code myself, and it seems a bit of a project in itself, so I'm hesitant. I'd like to get some guidance from those more experienced, as to what is actually most useful, before diving in.

1. what quantities are most useful to visualize?
2. how to display them?
3. how (and when) to select which one to display (a UI issue)?

> **EDIT** I should add, I'm developing on android (on the device itself, not on a PC), so many popular tools/apps aren't available. And, since my main project is to display real-time simulation, also visualizing some data isn't that different a task.

Comment: I am not sure I understand. Do you wish to debug the results of your simulation (Velocity, pressure, etc.) or the visualization aspect? For the latter, I believe a simple unit testing approach is more efficient. For the former, you should really look into something like the method of manufactured solutions to be sure the solution you are getting is good.

Comment: @BlaisB Thanks, I meant the former; edited to clarify. "Manufactured solutions": guess a class of analytical solution, then add the errors to the NS equations (as source terms), to make it correct. Now, can check simulation results with it. Clever! But seems to need industrial stength tools to work out the analytical errors. ["several pages to print out just the energy equation source term"](http://www.innovative-cfd.com/manufactured-solutions-overview.html). I think my openGL rendering (visualization) code is OK - but I'm curious: how could unit testing be applied to it?

Comment: I have regrouped my two comments as an answer, I think this presents a clearer perspective.

Comment: The **pressure**. It's easier to explore since it is a scalar. And if something's going wroing you will see it in the pressure first.

Comment: @Jan Thanks, that makes sense. Actually, I started with pressure$^{1}$, but because I'm using compressible equations, you get pressure waves everywhere, and it's hard to see what's going on. But maybe there's a way to make it clearer, because you're right... maybe, somehow have waves with smaller magnitude than larger-scale pressure variations? Or, wait for it to settle down to a steady-state? **[1]** actually density, not pressure; and actually water depth, not density - but the point still stands.

Answer (score 2):

A good way to obtain to verify the CFD portion of your code is to proceed using the method of manufactured solution (MMS). You can look at the book by [Oberkampf & Roy](https://www.amazon.ca/Verification-Validation-Scientific-Computing-Oberkampf/dp/0521113601) or even this article by [me](http://sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0045793015000675).

The key principle of MMS is to decide on an analytical solution to your problem (in this case a velocity and/or pressure profile) and, using a symbolic calculator, to calculate the source term that corresponds to this flow profile inserted within the Navier-Stokes equation.

There are numerous commercial (Matlab, Mathematica, Maple) or open source (Python + SymPy, Sage) ways to calculate this source term. I have found that SymPy is super easy to use and is very efficient. The source terms can be quite long, but if you take trigonometric functions in your flow profile, they generally simplify to simple expressions. You can take the flow profile from my article as an example.

Comment: Thanks, SymPy beats my tedious and error-prone manual calculation! (Android: `termux`from play store; `apt install python`, `pip install sympy`). I wanted to ask: have you used the div, curl, grad of sympy? Or expand them by hand, just using sympy for the actual differentiation (as I did)? For your VANS article, would you use/define $\otimes$ and leave the whole substitution of MS into VANS eqs to sympy? But I see you choose a mass conserving MS, and use shortcuts (for steady state **s**, $\partial \mathbf s /\partial t=0$; and div-free **u** sends terms with $\nabla \cdot \mathbf u$ to zero).

Comment: Also, is a "transient regime" exactly the opposite of "steady state", in that the former has a solution dependent on time **t**, while the latter is independent of time (no **t** in the solution)?

Comment: Also, some more terminology: is a "flow profile" the manufactured solution for velocity, e.g. $\mathbf u (\mathbf x, t)$ ? i.e. a function defining the velocity of the flow across every point in space and every moment in time (within the domain). So, your equation `(18)`, for _Case 1_?

Comment: In my cases  I had some test cases with div u not equal to 0, because of the VANS equations. However, if you have regular Navier-stokes, I suggest you choose U such that by construction div u = 0.  Actually I did like you did, I would calculate each derivative one by one using Simpy, I felt more secure that way and it was super fast anyway. To me a transient regime (or solution) is a solution such that $$u=u(t,x)$$ therefore, with a non-zero time derivative. Similarly, a flow profile is a solution for velocity $$u=u(x,t)$$ a function that defines $$u(x,t)$$ everywhere in space/time.

Comment: Thanks very much! Also, I didn't realize we could do non-inline (forgotten the correct term) latex in comments, like $$ this. $$

Comment: No prob, pleasure is mine. MMS is regretfully not used enough in the verification of CFD codes. To me, I cannot trust CFD results if at least MMS has not been carried out... If you code does not follow the theoretical order of convergence in MMS cases, then something, somewhere is inconsistent.

Comment: Pedagogically, I like that it connects analytical and numerical solutions, which I find is lost in CFG (but maybe that's me: I'm only half a year in, starting from half-forgotten half-understood maths 101, so I appreciate this connection). I'm going to read through Roache 2002 overview (that your article suggested), to gradually get on top of it. I also feel that it's state-of-the-art verification... yet I'm still struggling with the basics (e.g. advecting velocity over a MAC grid). I fear my difficulties are too elementary for it to help! :) But it's interesting.

Comment: Actually, I could apply it to advection of velocity. I've heard that advection is the non-linear part of NS that makes analytical solutions elusive. And that advection was problematic in CFD for many years.

Comment: Problem with MMS is that it assumes you know how to discretize source terms

Comment: @PhilipRoe But wouldn't you just get the wrong answer? Or is it that, in order to run the simulation, you'll need to discretize the source terms. And if you discretize incorrectly on both sides (i.e. the rest of the governing equation and the source terms), they incorrectness (likely) cancel out, so discretization isn't tested?

Comment: @BlaisB you have the PDE, then discretization/estimation introduce error; and, your implementation could have bugs. It would be nice to verify your numerical result with an analytical result. But there aren't any for NS. So you manufacture one. But, there's still discretion/estimation errors. However the error in a correct numerical solution changes with the grid-size in a know way: proportional to the grid-size to the power of the order of the estimation. Therefore, you can graph the error against the grid-size, and see if it is linear, quadratic (or whatever the order of the estimation is.)

Comment: @BlaisB It seems to me that using this "proportional to" order of convergence is a bit loose. Wouldn't it be better to calculate exactly what the error bounds should be, and compare that? (Roache 2002 mentions calculating the co-officient *C*, but says they don't do it). It seems a bit magical...or does the convergence approach have some better accuracy qualities?

Comment: @BlaisB One could run the simulation, and check it against the "true" solution at each timestep, but accumulating errors could quickly separate them (especially "chaotic" turbulence). I see in the 3 examples in your article, the first two are steady-state - so I guess, for each run at a fiven grid-size, you run it til it reaches equilibrium, before recording its result. But the third one is transient, not steady state, and you take the result at $t=2s$. My question is: is the timestep $2s$? Or is it smaller, and you run each simulation several timeateps to reach $2s$ (accumukating errors)?

Comment: @hyperpallium Many questions! The transient case is run at constant CFL. I mention it in the article, thus the time step decreases at the same rate as the mesh size. Theoretically, if your scheme is second order in space, you should recover second order convergence in space. If you do not, there is an arrer somewhere somehow with your discretization. This way of measuring the order of convergence is super sensitive, an error in a single mesh element, at a single node, on a single boundary, will lower the order of convergence and you will catch it.

Comment: @hyperpallium. In many circumstances, discretizing the source terms is a major source of error. For example, shallow water flow with variation of the bottom surface. You discretize the differentiated terms using the best approved methods, and add in the source terms point wise. Then try the evil lake problem Free surface height = constant, velocity identically zero.
The lake will start to move spontaneously. Schemes that avoid this are called well-balanced and their construction is non-trivial. put "well-balanced schemes"into Google Scholar.

Comment: This is a universal difficulty with methods that put a lot of physics into the derivative terms. This subtlety must be matched in the source terms. Solving non-physical problems is risky way to validate your code unless you know exactly what you are doing.

Comment: @BlaisB Thank you! I see that a changing CFL could change the error behaviour (e.g. if $\Delta x$ gets smaller, but $\Delta t$ stays the same, the distance covered per timestep increases, crossing more of a grid cell, or even several). But you don't have constant CFL for the two steady state cases? Also, smaller $\Delta x$ means more grid-cells, and longer compute times (and I see you cover > 10x $\Delta x$) - could one instead shrink the domain, thus keeping the number of cells constant? Or would that upset the error convergence, being a different problem?

Comment: @BlaisB I've just read around "order of convergence": is it usually the same "order" as the (eg) finite difference scheme? (I guess this is a whole separate topic but) how are the theoretical orders of convergence arrived at (e.g. *eq (16)* in your article)? Also, maybe I'm mixing discretization vs. calculating derivatives, but: *2nd-order for cell face interpolations and gradients* (p9, just above section 4).  and later *linear space discretization* (p12, just above *(17)*) seem in contradiction? The order of convergence ends up being 2.

Comment: @BlaisB Finally, this is probably a whole new topic, but can you give me a hint as to *why* the order of convergence method is so sensitive? I see that, given $\Delta x < 1$, $E \propto (\Delta x) ^ p$ increases as $p$ decreases. Therefore, "lower[ing] the order of convergence" $p$ increases the error $E$. So that's how you tell something's awry... and by exercising different terms, you can narrow it down. but *how much* different must it be, to be amiss? In your article, $2.01$ and $2.02$ are close enough to $2$ (and graphs do look very close!)... how do you know that's close enough?

Comment: @BlaisB BTW I would have thought averaging the Euclidean distance of errors over the whole file could hide one or more spurious values? (but I guess that applies to calculating the error, not the convergence)

Comment: @PhilipRoe Thanks! I don't quite understand, but I've grabbed a few pdfs from Scholar and will look over them. I'm obviously on the far side of being an expert, though, I can see that historically, discretizing simple advection gave a lot of trouble, so maybe problems lurk in discretizing source terms too, derived from arbitrary manufactured solutions. OTOH it seems a very comforting verification against implementation bugs, even if not "theorem-like" confidence as Roache2002 claimed. And if source term discretization is problematic, it will just fail, rather than give false confidence.

Comment: @BlaisB Wait, only a *lower* order of convergence indicates a problem; $2.02$ shows it's getting more accurate *faster* than expected (how would that happen?). I'm not sure of the statistics for curve fitting, but $2.02$ might be a reasonable error for only 17 or so data points (though, to my uninformed intuition, 1% seems a bit high). Perhaps it's still converging a bit?

Comment: You should try to avoid to have discussions in the comment section. If you have an error in your scheme, you will see the order of convergence reduce drastically and you error will level off to a plateau. The order of convergence is generally greatly affected if there is an error in your scheme (reduction to order 1, or order zeroth). The rate of convergence of a scheme is only asymptotic, so if you are getting 2.02 instead of 2.00, like in my case, it just means that i have not reached the asymptotic region of my convergence yet (but I am close to it).

Comment: As for the Second order and linear interpolation, I fear you have something confused. A linear scheme, like for instance P1 elements in finite element, exhibit second order convergence when you look at the L2 norm of the error. It is classically known that elements of order $p$ have L2 convergence of order $p+1$ if your problem is well posed. It is the same for the finite difference or finite volume method.

Comment: @BlasiusB; Its subtler than that. A finite-volume method using only cell averages can be of any order depending on the reconstruction. Discontinuous Galerkin methods are order $2p+1$ under favorable circumstances. And @hyperpallium, 2.02, 1.97 are normal (in fact very good) for nonlinear problems.

Comment: I learnt something today :). I am not very familiar with DG methods, i've generally only worked with cell centered / vertex centered Finite volumes or Petrov-Galerkin / Garlekin FEM. :)

Comment: @BlaisB Thanks very much! I could add different bugs, to get a feel for how the order of convergence is affected.

Answer (score 1):

Creation of own visualisation code, it is hard to justify, unless you will have some strong arguments why existing codes are not good enough. It is a couple of great open codes.

You can do visualisation on the fly when you do analysis, http://www.paraview.org/in-situ/ great tool, or as result of post-processing, see Paraview, openDX, visit a large number of possibilities.

Paraviev catalyst is particularly interesting; you can link your app. to it and do all in parallel when your run the analysis.

Comment: Thanks, I'm developing on an android device (not just for it; i.e. no PC is involved), so I thought tools would not be available. But through your answer, I found http://www.kiwiviewer.org/ an "open source...visualization app for exploring scientific...datasets that runs on Android...devices". I'll have to work out its fileformat, and try it out. From your paraview link, it's interesting that most visualization is *post hoc*, not *in situ*.BTW opendx.org seems down.

Comment: I had a play with kiwiviewer. It's very smooth, and has some pretty cool touch controls, for zooming, and enabling/disabling layers; but no scales. You also can't add your own data (it has presets, or you can use a http: url - bit not a file:) It seems intended for use as a library, but requires ant for compilation, which I don't have access to.

Comment: On the plus side, I realize it's very easy to automatically scale nicely, if you can look at all the data before displaying: just note the range.  BTW a pure java library is another alternative for android (kiwiviewer is C++, though with bindings).